# While Loop that reads non-negative values and terminates when a value less than 0 is read

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a problem in a Java Code Lab that reads as this:

Give that two  int variables,  total and  amount have been declared, write a loop that reads non-negative values into  amount and adds them into  total . The loop terminates when a value less than 0 is read into  amount .

My output either says that I am including a negative value in my sum OR I seem to be stopping at zero, depending on how I code the statement.

My loop is as follows:

```
total = 0;
amount = 0;
while( amount > -1 )
{

amount = TC.getNum();

total = total + amount;
}
```

This particular one says I seem to be stopping at zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code adds `amount` **unconditionally** to `total`, and then checks if it should have terminated before doing that. Try:

```
total = 0;
amount = 0;
do {
    total = total + amount;
    amount = TC.getNum();
} while ( amount > -1 );
```

or:

```
total = 0;
amount = 0;
while(true) {
    amount = TC.getNum();
    if (amount < 0)
        break;
    total = total + amount;
}
```

I'm not sure myself which I like better.

Edit: I think I like the second version better. It reads more naturally, and the first one may confuse due to a superfluous (and potentially error-prone) `total = total + 0` at the very start of the loop.

Comment: That did the trick. Not sure why I thought I shouldn't add an If statement to this exercise. Stupid me. The 2nd version at least for me is definitely easier to understand at first glance.

Thank you very much for the help. That was the last problem I needed to complete!

Comment: Don't forget about `total += amount`

Comment: @JustinMuller I prefer changing the OP's code as least as I can, to make it easier for them to follow the real changes. I would have used += otherwise though, yes. (Is that what you meant?)

Comment: @lfry: Yes, that is what I meant.  I wanted to point out the existence of += to Abweichung

Comment: @JustinMuller Btw, you can press <kbd>TAB</kbd> for autocompletion after typing in `@` and the first character (or a few characters) if a person's name ;-)